# Internet Explorer 11 F12 key debugger tools, how to save HTML built from ajax?

Tags: internet-explorer

You know in old versions of internet explorer before 11 you had F12 and, after pages was loaded, you could save the built pages (from jQuery Ajax) and work with the complete web page.

in the current version, internet explorer 11, how can I save the complete HTML code?

I think Microsoft take off the save buttons from debugger tools and they set Console.

Could somebody confirm it?

Answer (score 2):

Open the F12 tools, Go to the network tab. Hit the green arrow to enable the network waterfall. Then after the request has been made look at the request details. Select the ResponseBody, you can right-click and select save as. See my screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Hi david... if this was the right answer, please click the checkbox beside it to indicate so! Thanks!